# How to get the object type from a collection (vector) of parent objects using RTTI

Tags: c++, vector, rtti

I have a base class which has two child classes derived from it.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
```

I have another class that has a pointer to collection of class A members using a vector, something like this:

```
vector<A*> *m_collection;
```

And what I do is to create objects of class B or C and add them to the collection using push_back:

```
B *myb = new B();
m_collection->push_back(myb);
```

Then I loop through the collection and try to check using 'typeid', but it always returns the base class (A). Is it not possible to know the exact type?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't try to format your code using HTML tags - use the formatting buttons above the text editing area.

Comment: The best way to do markup of a block of code is to indent it four spaces. That automatically escapes special characters like "<".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there is unlikely to be a reason to create your vector dynamically  using new. Simply say:

```
vector<A*> m_collection;
```

Then you need to give your base class a virtual function or two. A virtual destructor would be  a good start:

```
class A {
   public:
     virtual ~A() {}
};
```

without it you cannot safely write code like:

```
m_collection.push_back( new B );
delete m_collection[0];
```

Doing this will also enable run-time type information. Howver, switching on `typeid` is not how C++ likes you to use RTTI - you should use `dynamic_cast`:

```
m_collection.push_back( new B );    // or new A or new C
if ( C * c = dynamic_cast<C *>( m_collection[0] ) ) {
   c->CFunc():  // function in C
}
else if ( B * b = dynamic_cast<B *>( m_collection[0] ) ) {
   b->BFunc():  // function in B
}
else if ( A * a = dynamic_cast<A *>( m_collection[0] ) ) {
   a->AFunc():  // function in A
}
else {
  throw "unknown type";
}
```

In general however, it is better to use the virtual function mechanism for dispatch, rather than RTTI.

Comment: Why is dynamic_cast<> preferred to directly using typeid ?

Comment: @Hassan: I don't think it should be. You should also be able to use typeid and follow that with a static_cast. (Might be more efficient, since checking typeid could be a lot simpler than dynamic_cast.) However, still the existance of virtual methods would be required.

Comment: dynamic_cast is safer - this is BS's opinion, as well as my own.

Comment: Usign the dynamic_cast does not imply you are using RTTI? What is actually confirm the use of it?

Comment: @Julen dynamic_cast requires RTTI. You can confirm this by turning RTTI off (if your compiler supports this).

Comment: I am using GCC right now, I work using automake/autoconf (quite misterious but useful to me) and I don't know exactly how to turn it off... :-(

Answer (score 0):

W.r.t. typeid, you need to have a virtual function in your base class (A) (the vtable usually sits near the std::type_info structure), then you must dereference the object, i.e. `typeid(*b)`.